# How to post data with fetch to functions.php

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, fetch

I am trying to make a fetch request to the `functions.php` file. I am trying to avoid jQuery and Ajax thats why I am using the standard fetch API.

My code in one of my theme pages:

```
<button @click="load()">test</button>
```

And the script part in the same file:

```
<script>
function load() {

    fetch('<?php echo admin_url('admin-post.php'); ?>', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'x-requested-with': 'XMLHttpRequest'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                action: 'my-action'
            })
        }).then(data => {
        console.log(data);
    })
}
</script>
```

The Code in my `functions.php` file:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_my_action' , 'data_fetch');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_my_action','data_fetch');

function data_fetch(){
    echo "hi";
}
```

In the console the response works but it doesnt return anything. I think it just finds the file so it returns 200 but the `data_fetch` function is never executed.

How can I get this to work?

Thanks for your help ;).

I followed this post: https://www.it-swarm.dev/de/functions/ajax-live-suche-nach-posttitel/961942434/

Comment: The jQuery AJAX functionality that is normally used, sends an additional request header `x-requested-with: XMLHttpRequest` - it might be that WordPress needs that one to recognize this as an AJAX request in the first place.

Comment: Thank you very much. I added the header ;). But still not getting a response ;(.

Comment: @CBroe the problem with Fetch API, It does'nt show server error. Use ajax of jQuery or Axios.

Comment: I don’t get what the point is in “trying to avoid jQuery and Ajax” to begin with here, nearly any WP theme you’ll find uses jQuery, and the whole admin backend does, too.

Comment: `body: JSON.stringify` is most certainly wrong, the WP AJAX endpoint expects a standard form-urlencoded request.

Comment: I am coding my theme from scratch. And do everything in vanilla js. Fair point but the admin jquery is not loaded on the client side.

Comment: ahhh very good to know I will have a deeper look in the docs of the ajax endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

i think you dont need to use specific header request for that example

also , try with `FormData()` :

```js
"use strict";

(function () {
  var data = new FormData();  // create an Object and take your data
  data.append("action", "my-action");
  fetch([Object Object], { // use your ajax url instead of ***[Object Object]***
    method: "POST",
    credentials: "same-origin",
    body: data, // put your data into fetch body
  })
    .then((response) => response.text())
    .then((data) => {
      if (data) {
        console.log(data);
      }
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log("[ OPS!! my_action ]");
      console.error(error);
    });
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add action to the url as argument, this works for me

```
.....
fetch('<?php echo admin_url('admin-post.php') . "?action=my-action"; ?>', {
.....
```